# Splitting voltage and current unevenly

Tags: power-supply, variable, split

I want to make my lab variable power supply from an old laptop power adapter (19V 6A) with an LCD to show Volts and Amps. The LCD needs an independent powersupply. Can I make a circuit to give me the power from the laptop supply in a way that is 'independent' or should I find another solution?

This is what I have in mind. Just a couple of Buck Converters, one of them will have the POT's moved to the front of the case and the other small one to power the LCD, fixed at 5v.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVDn13.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: "Independent" from what?

Comment: Typically the supply for the metering / display electronics would be a different circuit path.  Ie, if it is supplied from the same source and not a different one, then you would have a regulator supplying these electronics, and in parallel with that a distinct path that goes through your current sensor to the load / load regulator.

Comment: You are probably not going to get much in the way of variable output voltage from a laptop power adapter.  Just what sort of output range do you need?

Comment: This is the schematic given by the LCD Supplier. I am pretty happy with 12V for now. [Schematic](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzDodzXifU-0eVdzRjlxNUpkOEk/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

You need to clarify what you mean by "independent power supply"

If you mean the LCD needs an appropriate voltage to run, and that voltage must be fixed, and independent from the voltage output by your power supply, then yes - you can just use your laptop adapter to generate two separate output voltage lines. One of them with low current (assuming LCD draws milliamps) and fixed voltage. The other a variable voltage, where the laptop's 19V are reduced using either a linear regulator (simple but difficult to construct for larger amperage), or a buck regulator - much more difficult to implement but can handle larger current without an excessively big heatsink and fan.

If you mean the LCD needs to be galvanically isolated from the voltage provided by the lab supply - it is going to be very difficult. You need to convert DC to AC, pass it "through" a transformer, get it back to DC. This is a tall order for anyone who doesn't specialize in PSUs.

Maybe you are actually asking on how to measure the voltage / current of your supply, and display those on an LCD. You should improve your question by adding a circuit you are considering for the actual "supply" part, and then we could help about the LCD portion.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. Here is the schematic provided by the LCD supplier. [Schematic](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzDodzXifU-0eVdzRjlxNUpkOEk/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

*Figure 1. Battery powered LCD voltmeter.*

If you're stuck with only your 19 V laptop supply I would recommend that you purchase two LCD voltmeters and power each from a 9 V battery. This means that you can connect them on the high side or low side of your bench power supply to measure voltage and current as required without risk of damage through common grounds, etc. These typically have very low current consumption and the battery will last for a long time.

Alternatively you could use a couple of 6 to 9 V wall warts to provide independent power to each unit.

The only alternative to power from your laptop supply is to use an isolating DC/DC power supply which may be more trouble than it's worth.

Most of these meters read full-scale at 199.9 mV so you need to add a voltage divider for the voltmeter and a shunt for the ammeter. Since your PSU is rated for 6 A your ammeter will read 6.00 at 6 A. This will occur at 60 mV so your shunt will need to be \$ R = \frac {V}{I} = \frac {60m}{6} = 10~m\Omega \$.

If you can find a meter such as shown in Figure 1 you can enable the 'V' and 'A' units on the display which is a nice touch.

Answer (score 0):

Knock the 19V down to a regulated 12V with an LM7812 and then use an **isolated** DC-DC converter module to give you +5 or +/-5 or whatever your meter modules require.

An LED meter might use 0.5W so the LM7812 will only dissipate a couple hundred mW and no need for a heat sink for powering one or two DC-DC converters. LCD meters will probably use even less, depending on the backlight consumption.

You could also make the DC-DC converter from scratch and wind your own transformer, say on a pot core, (perhaps omitting the LM7812) but it's not too cost effective for a one off-- the core, bobbin, wire and a suitable chip will likely cost more than the module.